# Javascript not inheriting style

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, styles, wordpress-theming

What's up Stack!  I am having a major problem with a javascript form that I have implemented on my company's website.  The problem is the form is not inheriting anything from the stylesheet.  All of our corporate websites are built using wordpress.  For this particular website, we are using the divi theme with a child theme for customization.  I have all the javascript files and php files that they call up on ftp and the form itself works just fine, but it is a complete jumbled mess visually.  I ended up setting up the same form in another test environment without divi and the form ended up being styled to match the different theme being used.  So I know the problem is divi, but does anyone have any advice on how to get this form styled whilst still using divi?

Here is the URL for the site in question:  http://www.haines.com/university/

Under select a class, when you click the date link in any of the classes, the form opens up.

Comment: *Broken Javascript Form Pic* - Should be *Broken JavaScript in post* (include your code in the post, not as an image).

Comment: The code is not what is broken.  The code works fine, but Divi is preventing the form from being styled.  So there is no need to post the code of the form.  The form gets styled just fine in any other wordpress theme, except Divi.

Comment: A url or form + css snippet would help you get an answer, cannot fix what we cannot see

Comment: I added the link to the site in the question.  I hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. **Some tips on using the site**: you are expected to have researched your issue and include your attempts to solve it including a [Minimal, Complete & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please [re-read the Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a few things going on here. I see that you're still actively changing the code, so this might not all apply currently.

First, you're re-using ids. You can't do that; an id is meant to be unique, and will cause issues if it is not. Change studentclasssignup to a class instead.

Secondly, you're putting the css on the div, when you want the input styled. You want the css on a child of the div. If you change to a class, you can style a child like this:

`.studentclasssignup > input {
     <whatever>
}`

Or with an id it would be:

`#studentclasssignup > input {
     <whatever>
}`

But again, do not reuse IDs.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much.  Once you said this, it clicked for me and I was able to figure out how to setup the class in my custom css form.  I now am on my way to getting this sucker styled!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, your template is using dynamic class in its CSS. For exemple :

```
.hs-form-c0074a25-1641-462d-8731-7da7bc52f872_06f8c9b0-accf-40a3-a90d-65b583641897 .hs-button{
    border:none;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

That means you cannot re-use their style, except if you know how to retrieve this kind of id.

In that case, the easiest thing should be to copy/paste the CSS you want, and apply it to your form like that :

```
.registercontainer button {
    border:none;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

That should be done for every style you need (input, label etc.)